# Parent selector in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table row that needs to be hidden when the anchor with class "removerow" is clicked.

```
<tr><td>Product Name</td><td><a class="removerow">Remove</a></td></tr>
```

I've been trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
$("a.removerow").click(function(){
$(tr > this).hide();
```

});

How can I select the entire table row with a child of ".removerow".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `closest(selector)` function will traverse upward and return the nearest selector provided.

(If the element clicked is the same as the given selector, then it returns that.)

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
$("a.removerow").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `e.preventDefault()` will disable the default behavior of the `a` element.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't have a parent selector, but it does have a [parent function](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Also, the tr is not the direct parent of the link.  Instead, it's two levels up (`td` is the first parent)

```
$("a.removerow").click(function(){
    // Called twice (first is td, second is tr)
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

If there are no other `tr`s in the hierarchy, you could also use

```
$("a.removerow").click(function(){
    // Called twice (first is td, second is tr)
    $(this).parents('tr').hide();
});
```

If the tr has a class on it, you could do this:

```
$("a.removerow").click(function(){
    // Called twice (first is td, second is tr)
    $(this).parents('.ClassNameHere').hide();
});
```